# Unable to train dataset for RCNN due to attribute error?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am currently following the tutorial by EdjeElectronics: https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10#1-install-anaconda-cuda-and-cudnn and I am in the step no:6. Run the Training. I had certain errors before but I cleared them so I have generated the TFrecords and I am stuck here.[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taVye.png)

If there are any files that I need to attach for your convenience pls let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contrib attribute has moved out of Tesnsorflow version 2.
To use version 1, replace the 'import tensorflow as tf' line as follows:

```
#import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf #using v1 of tf
```

Actually, when looking at this link - https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate, there is a line - 
It is still possible to run 1.X code, unmodified (except for contrib), in TensorFlow 2.0

The link goes to page - https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md which explains what happened to each contrib module.

You can try to migrate code to Tensorflow 2 or whatever version you are using.
Another alternative is to uninstall your Tensorflow installation and install Tensorflow with version 1.x.

Comment: should I change it for all the .py files

Comment: Yes, wherever you find the 'import tensorflow as tf' line.

Comment: It still does not work...it shows the same error with tf.compat.v1